# iOS 8 MkMapKit cannot Get Users Location

Tags: ios, ios8

when i am trying to get user location in iOS-8

iam getting this error

Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call

```
-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

I have implemented:if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [self.Mylocation requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.Mylocation requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

iam  getting device location as 0.00, 0.00

please help me

Comment: Have you included the relevant Plist key?

Comment: how to included relevant plist key

Answer (score 0):

In your Supporting Files folder, there should be a file called "your bundle identifier-Info.plist".

Depending on which type of location authorisation you are using (when in use or always) will determine what plist property you will need to add.

If you are using "always" usage, you will need to add the following identifier: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, then add a descriptive string as to why you need to use the location.

If you want to only access the location when the app is in use, you need to add the following property:`NSLocationWhenInUseDescription` and again, add a relevant description string.

Comment: hi i have other doute can u please help on that

Comment: when i keep my application in background and start opening other applications like google map my app is getting crash and showing alert as “app crash due to memory pressure in Xcode

Comment: Try adding the @autoreleasepool to the call of your method.